# jquery datepicker in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use jquery date picker on all datetime fields, so I have following inside my mvc3 project

Model

```
public DateTime? DateTime{ get; set; }
```

Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString(), new { @class = "date" })
```

and on _Layout.cshtml page I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".date").datepicker();
});
```

I have referenced datepicker css and other jquery files (jqueryui and jquery-1.5.1.js)

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

error message is following

```
TypeError: $(".date").datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]       
$(".date").datepicker();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have included `jquery` twice: the standard and the minified version. Get rid of one of  the two. Also make sure that your custom script comes **after** them:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".date").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt inculde the jQuery and jQuery UI(.js files not .css) libraries which this date picker belongs to.

Comment: actually I have included, just updated question with added js.

Comment: Your error message indicates absence of .Js files.Please check the jS files that you are including are getting included correctly on the page and also look if any of these files is not corrupt or blank.I think it should fix the problem.Or you can give us a URL to see this.

Answer (score 0):

I have few suggestions.

1. try updating jquery to the lates version which i think is 1.8.1
2. i dont think you need model.tostring just model shoud work in this cale // dont think this is causing the issue but just a suggestion